# soln to heat equation w/ linearly growing diffusivity

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = t\nabla^2 u  \longrightarrow u(x,0) = \delta(x) $$

Hi all, I was wondering what ways are possible to solve this. Using a scaling argument where $$u(\lambda x,\lambda^k t) = v(y,s)$$, but all I was able to obtain from this is the relation $$v_t = \lambda^{2-2k}\nabla^2 v $$ in the new coordinate system. I thought transforming this equation to be bounded on a disk would also work, in which I let $$r \longrightarrow \lambda r$$ & $$ t \longrightarrow \lambda t^2$$

From all this, I think you can say that $$ \lambda ~ t^{-1}$$ and plug in $$u(x,t) -> u(\frac{x}{t^2},1) = \Phi (r)$$ but I am not sure how this gets to a solution, or can be used towards the B.C. Should I rewrite the PDE in terms of $$ \Phi(r)$$so I can solve it?

Does anyone have any tips/help on how to get this into a form that I can integrate using Fourier transform? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: On the LHS we can write $t^{-1}\partial_t u $. Change variables so that this reads $\partial_s u$, using $s=t^2/2$, then you have the usual diffusion equation for $u(x,s)$

Comment: The solution $u$ only has dilations of the form $$u(x, t) \to u_{\lambda} := \lambda^{\alpha} u(x, \lambda^{\gamma} t)$$ that leave the equation invariant. The scaling $u(\lambda x, \lambda^{\gamma} t)$ leaves a factor of $\lambda^{2}$ acting on the Laplacian.

Comment: After Fourier transformation in the $x$ variable, $\frac{\partial \hat{u}}{\partial t} = -t|\xi|^2\hat{u}$, $\hat{u}(\xi, 0) = (2\pi)^{-n/2}$.